# cursor not changing on hover

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

i am having 4 links add visitor,add machine,add host,add operator ,i felt surprised to see that on hovering through the link the cursor icon is not changing.
here is my code

```
<div style="margin-left:800px;margin-top:-200px;"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="addvisitorui.php"><label for="addvisitor">ADD VISITOR</a></div>
            <div style="margin-left:800px;"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="addmachine/addmachineui.php"><label for="addmachine">ADD MACHINE</a></div>
            <div style="margin-left:800px;"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="addhost/addhostui.php"><label for="addhost">ADD HOST</a></div>
            <div style="margin-left:800px;"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="addoperator/addoperatorui.php"><label for="addoperator">ADD OPERATOR</a></div>
```

can any one say me what i am doing wrong.Thank you

Comment: it's invalid html.. you didn't close label tag!

Comment: How about providing [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can test your code?

Comment: add `cursor:pointer` in style in anchor after text-decoration style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove label from inside anchor tag or if u want to add label you can add it before anchor tag so i will perfect working

like

```
<div style="margin-left:800px;"><label for="addhost"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="addhost/addhostui.php">ADD HOST</a></label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use CSS but not in style="" rather in  block or .css file.

your code is not valid. For example there is no ending tag for label

to make hover use

```
<style>
a {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{color:red;}
div.mystyle{margin-left:800px;margin-top:-200px;}
</style>
```

Proper HTML

```
        <div class="mystyle"><a href="addvisitorui.php"><label for="addvisitor">ADD VISITOR</label></a></div>
        <div class="mystyle"><a href="addmachine/addmachineui.php"><label for="addmachine">ADD MACHINE</label></a></div>
        <div class="mystyle"><a href="addhost/addhostui.php"><label for="addhost">ADD HOST</label></a></div>
        <div class="mystyle"><a href="addoperator/addoperatorui.php"><label for="addoperator">ADD OPERATOR</label></a></div>
```

why do you use label tag anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the label tag by closing it, should solve your problem.

```
<div style="margin-left:800px;margin-top:-200px;">
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="addvisitorui.php">
        <label for="addvisitor">ADD VISITOR</label>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is malformed:

```
<div style="margin-left:800px;margin-top:-200px;">
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="addvisitorui.php">
        <label for="addvisitor">ADD VISITOR</label>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:800px;">
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="addmachine/addmachineui.php">
        <label for="addmachine">ADD MACHINE</label>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:800px;">
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="addhost/addhostui.php">
        <label for="addhost">ADD HOST</label>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:800px;">
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="addoperator/addoperatorui.php">
        <label for="addoperator">ADD OPERATOR</label>
    </a>
</div>
```

You'll also need to add a CSS rule to specify that the `label` should utilize the `pointer` cursor:

```
a label {
    cursor: pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
div style="cursor:pointer;margin-left:800px;"
```

The cursor will update to pointer when you hover over the div.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the following in your div's: `cursor:pointer`:

```
<div style="margin-left:800px; margin-top:-200px; cursor:pointer;">
   <a style="text-decoration:none" href="addvisitorui.php">
      <label for="addvisitor">
          ADD VISITOR
      </label>
   </a>
</div>
```